# Is there garbage collection on the GPU?

Tags: opengl, garbage-collection, glsl, gpu

As far as I understand, when memory is allocated in heap memory in a language without garbage collection, it needs to be freed. Languages with garbage collection automatically does this when all referencing variable goes out of scope. Leaked memory is claimed by the OS when the program terminates.

Is there a similar garbage collector on the GPU?

Say for example I create a VBO in OpenGL, would this buffer stay on the vram indefinitely? Is there a concept of heap / stack vram?

Another example would be if I were to create a program on the gpu with `glCreateProgram` and subsequently attaching a shader to it, how do I (If I need to at all) release the memory allocated for the program?

Comment: This is the same as with other programming languages. It depends on your language and compiler. For example JAVA have an garbage collector while in c you need to free your memory. And even stack is not always handled the same way. Call via Register/Stack.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand that in the context of OpenGL, because code is still written in c++ and compiled for the CPU. However as I've read, when we call functions to push data to the buffer, the data is simply moved to the GPU. What would be the language and compiler involved?

Comment: Local variables ("on the stack") being deallocated when they go out of scope is *not* garbage collection in any sense of the word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like a lot of things with OpenGL, it depends on the implementation. The specification gives a lot of room for different driver implementations.

For example, [`glDeleteTextures`](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDeleteTextures.xml) states:

> After a texture is deleted, it has no contents or dimensionality, and its name is free for reuse (for example by glGenTextures).

The only thing that is immediately guaranteed is that the name (integer value returned by `glGenTextures`) is available again. It says nothing about whether or not that memory has actually been cleaned yet.

If a driver wanted to implement a garbage collector that went around and cleaned up the actual memory behind buffers that have already been deleted, they could. A simpler implementation would just clean up everything before returning.

There is also no guarantee that the data ends up in VRAM. Depending on a number of factors, some of your buffers may end up in regular RAM.

To more directly answer you questions:

1. Mostly explained above, it depends on the driver.
2. Yes, until the context that the VBO was created in is deleted.
3. Again, depends on the driver. There isn't really a stack in the traditional sense, you have thousands of cores doing floating point math at different times. Shader operations are probably loaded in some sort of instruction cache/stack format which would vary for different groups of cores. Most of VRAM is just heap for your textures/vertices/other blobs of data
4. You should detatch/delete your shaders after creating a program. I answered this on gamedev.stackexchange a while ago: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/47912/12191

Comment: Why does the spec give implementors room here? From the user's perspective, it is clearly specified what object deletion entails and when it takes place. There is nothing said about when the allocated memory is released but that's not important from the user's perspective - as long as it is released before another allocation that may otherwise fail is done, it's fine. Also, no implementation is permitted to `just clean up everything` before returning - there are various in-use conditions to be taken into account. Please clarify - preferably with spec contents.

Comment: @thokra: The spec gives room here, because (tautology incoming) it's a specification. It describes the behaviour visible to the user of the API. Anything that's going on behind the scenes is irrelevant for the specification of an API. When writing such kind of a specification you never know which kind of system or runtime environment it's going to be implemented at. And thus it would be foolish to try to pin down any details on the inner workings.

Comment: @thokra: Heck, the kind of GPUs you can find in the wild already differ in such stark ways that it's actually impossible to pin down such "trivial" things like rasterization execution order without impairing efficient implementation of at least half of the GPUs out there (mobile GPUs work in very different ways than Desktop GPUs).

Comment: @datenwolf: I'm aware of the scope of the spec and how different HW architectures behave. The fact is, the observable behavior regarding object lifetime is clearly specified and everything else is completely irrelevant from the user's perspective - you simply don't care how the implementation handles memory (de-)allocations (yeah, you eventually do care when it comes to memory *access*). IMHO, the answer falls short to make that abundantly clear and also that you sill have the responsibility to clean stuff up, even though you don't actually (de-)allocate anything directly.